# If a method only has assignments, does it make sense to await that method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have this method called `MapRateRequestAsync`, which returns an object.

```
public async Task<ExternalRateRequest> MapRateRequestAsync(Request request, string currency, List<string> something)
{
    ExternalRateRequest req = new ExternalRateRequest();
    original_wt_unit = null;

    if (req.shipment == null)
        req.shipment = new ExternalRateShipment();
                

    if (request.@return != null)
    {
        if (req.shipment.Return == null)
            req.shipment.Return = new Address();

        req.shipment.Return.Attn = request.@return.name;
        req.shipment.Return.Company = request.@return.company;
        req.shipment.Return.AddressLine1 = request.@return.address_line1;
        req.shipment.Return.AddressLine2 = request.@return.address_line2;
        req.shipment.Return.AddressLine3 = request.@return.address_line3;
        req.shipment.Return.City = request.@return.city;     
  
        if (req.shipment.PackageList != null &&
            req.shipment.PackageList.Count() > 0)
        {
            req.shipment.PackageList[0].Description = request.customs.description;

            if (request.customs.customs_items != null)
            {
                req.shipment.PackageList[0].TradeItemList = new List<TradeItem>();

                foreach (var custitems in request.customs.customs_items)
                {
                    req.shipment.PackageList[0].TradeItemList.Add(new TradeItem
                    {
                        PricePerUnit = custitems.item_value,
                        Description = custitems.description,
                        Quantity = custitems.quantity,
                        Sku = custitems.sku
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    return await Task.FromResult(req);
}
```

It being called here, then it has to serialize, and then passed to a method which makes an async HTTP call:

```
theReq = await new something().MapRateRequestAsync(req,
    Currency, whatever); 

Request = serializeobject(theReq);

var response = await HttpCallClass.SendApiReq("POST", Request);
```

So is there any advantage I am getting in making `MapRateRequestAsync`, await for result, then awaiting for `MapRateRequestAsync` before serializing?

Comment: Why did you make this `async` if there's no asynchronous code at all? Everything runs synchronously. Adding `async` doesn't make the code run in the background, it's only syntactic sugar that allows using `await` to await already executing asynchronous operations

Comment: actually its not my code, this is a sample form where I work, just wanted to confirm, otherwise my thoughts are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question here seems to be: "should MapRateRequestAsync be async?"; currently, it doesn't need to do any async operations, as shown by the reality that you're using `Task.FromResult`. Note: you could remove the `async` and `await` and *just*  `return Task.FromResult(req);`, which would make what you have more efficient *but* could change the way exceptions are surfaced, slightly.

So yes, this *could* be made non-async and just have the return value as `ExternalRateRequest` rather than `Task<ExternalRateRequest>` - presumably renaming it to  `MapRateRequest`. However, that means that you can't *refactor* it later to *be* truly async if needed. If that is never going to be a concern: sure, do that. Likewise, if you're fine with breaking with API later if needed: sure, do that.

However, if you think that you *might genuinely* need this method to be truly async later *and* you don't want to break the API (because this is a public component with external consumers, for example): then it needs to be awaitable now. What you have isn't *hugely* inefficient, although it does allocate an unnecessary task each time. That isn't big, but if this is used *a lot*, you could consider having the return type as `ValueTask<ExternalRateRequest>` instead of `Task<ExternalRateRequest>`, with `return new(req);` instead of using `Task.FromResult`. This can still be trivially changed to be `async` later without breaking the API, but: it doesn't require any `Task<T>` allocations in the synchronous path.